# JSON.parse() failing due to unescaped double quotes

Tags: javascript, json, qualtrics

I am using a survey tool called Qualtrics, in that I am creating a workflow which pulls data from an API. the returned Data is in the following format:

```json
{"feedback_type":"Dining","reservation_id":"1234","order_id":null,"recommend_to_friend":"No","overall":"2","food":"3","ambience":"4","service":"5","notes":"The food was \"AWESOME\""}
```

The data is in JSON format, this then gets used in the next task in the workflow called as the [code task](https://www.qualtrics.com/support/survey-platform/actions-module/code-task/) (uses JavaScript) so that we can process this data.

What I am doing is

```
JSON.parse(`{"feedback_type":"Dining","reservation_id":"1234","order_id":null,"recommend_to_friend":"No","overall":"2","food":"3","ambience":"4","service":"5","notes":"The food was \"AWESOME\""}`)
```

Which is failing due to double quote breaking the JSON format.

This is the only way I can pull data in the code task (in a string).

I tried using regex to replace the problemeatic double quote but i was not able to figure out way to only remove/replace the one we wanted gone.

Comment: I think the proper way to escape the quotation marks would be `\\\"`; can you replace `\"` with `\\\"`?

Comment: or replace `\"` with `"` ...

Comment: it's actually `\\"` you need

Comment: This is the language in language problem. JSON needs escaping, regular JavaScript string literals need escaping too, and both languages use the same escape sequence.

Comment: If the JSON string is sent to you by the API as you have shown, then there should be no problem parsing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot simply copy/paste a raw output string in your code and expect it to work. In Javascript source code you either need to escape backslashes by doubling them, or, preferably, use `String.raw`:

```js
 result = JSON.parse(String.raw`{"feedback_type":"Dining","reservation_id":"1234","order_id":null,"recommend_to_friend":"No","overall":"2","food":"3","ambience":"4","service":"5","notes":"The food was \"AWESOME\""}`)

console.log(result)
console.log(result.notes)
```